# Android Size Resolution Should I Disable?

Tags: android, size, screen, resolution, unity-game-engine

I want my application to work on all non-tablets atleast.
I am tempteded to change android:anyDensity=false; and have the support screens all to false except
normal. But I wont be able to reach everyone's phone. Is this a big deal? Is this the best practice (below)

My main concern is that my application will have objects bigger than the screen size.

Important Note : I am developing my application in Unity3D. (Don't hate I grew up on Eclipse like the rest of you guys for 2 yrs on the android SDK)

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/screens.html

From that chart you can see that targeting normal-mdpi and normal-hpdi will cover almost 90% of the devices on the market; the outliers are likely to be quite old or obscure.